# How to deal with SonarQube marking Jackson StdDeserializer with "no-arg constructor missing" Bug

Tags: jackson, sonarqube

I am creating a custom deserializer by extending the Jackson StdDeserializer and I am getting complaints from SonarQube ["Add a no-arg constructor to StdDeserializer"](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/serialization/RSPEC-2055)

What is the proper way of dealing with this?

Comment: Does it work without no-arg constructor? Can you deserialise payload with it? You should add no-arg constructor like in this example [Getting Started with Custom Deserialization in Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

Comment: @MichałZiober The issue is SQ is complaining a 3rd-party class (Jackson's StdDeserializer) is missing the no-arg constructor. My own class that extends the StdDeserializer *does have* said constructor. I wonder if I am expected to edit a 3rd-party class, which obviously sounds funny as a solution. :)

Comment: Now I understand. I would just try to ignore it and exclude all 3-rd party jars from checking process.

Comment: I should have added that the warning itself, despite complaining about Jackson's StdDeserializer class, is rendered in *my custom deserializer class.* I.e. Sonar probably does not scan any JARs, and only inspects the StdDeserielizer (which is in JAR) because it is a super-class to my class. In the end I added //NOSONAR tag to the offending line.